# Using Blender to animate CAD mechanisms?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, import, rigid-body-simulation

I want to try and use Blender to animate a CAD drawing that I've made (for a visualization).  Is blender capable of this?  I *can* get a CSV file with time and an angle from the differential equation analysis (using Octave with ODE45), so if I wanted to import the list of values into blender, could I do that (an example would be a pendulum with values returned for angle)?  How would the different parts of the assembly be made to interact?

Comment: Keep to one question at a time. Yes blender is capable, start by looking through some tutorials on animating pistons/cylinders [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KpgC29Pc9A) and ask a more specific question when you get stuck. Blender has many import addons that can be enabled, [compare this list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts#Import-Export_Scripts) against what you can export from octave.

Comment: When I get a pointlist from octave, I'm talking about a list of x-positions or a list of theta (rotation angle) values which describe the motion, not the 3D object (sorry if that was unclear).  Basically I can get a list of values with respect to time

Comment: You can do all of these things, but you have to implement the mechanics using blender's various features such as drivers, modifiers, constraints, etc. Blender is not a parametric program like solidworks, which makes simulations like this more complicated to achieve but still possible with a bit of work (as @sambler mentioned in his links).

Comment: You can use python to translate the input into keyframes. But as said your question(s) is/are too unspecific to answer.